# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "Haarspalterei" und "Erbsenzählerei"?

Tags: difference, idiom, noun

Die beiden Begiffe *Haarspalterei* und *Erbsenzählerei* lassen sich auch als Eigenschaften Personen zuschreiben.

> Er ist ein Haarspalter.
>
> Er ist ein Erbsenzähler.

Gibt es Unterschiede zwischen diesen beiden Begriffen oder sind sie jeweils austauschbar?

Comment: Das ist nun wirklich bloß pedantische Wortklauberei! ;-)

Comment: Vielleicht? Kombiniere es mal mit **endlos**

Comment: Irgendjemand sollte seinen Erbsen-Count raufgezählt bekommen, indem @bernd_k eine Antwort acceptet ;-D

Comment: Viel interessanter ist doch die *Erbsenspalterei*.

Answer (score 19):

*Seh ich anders als alle anderen Antwortenden:*

**Erbsenzählerei** benutzt zum Beispiel der Steuerberater, der den Aufwand für eine Detailabrechnung fürchtet, während der Pauschalbetrag in der Steuererklärung den gleichen Effekt hätte. **Gemeint sind viele einzelne Kleinigkeiten zu unterscheiden und in irgendeiner Form zu quantifizieren.** Haarspalterei wäre das nicht, denn es ist ja möglich, die Einzelbeträge zu erklären anstelle eines Pauschbetrags.

**Haarspalterei** mag Erbsenzählerei oft einschliessen, aber nicht umgekehrt. Jede Erbsenzählerei kann man als Haarspalterei bezeichnen, aber nicht jede Haarspalterei ist Erbsenzählerei. Zum Beispiel kann man die Frage als Haarspalterei sehen, aber eher nicht als Erbsenzählerei, denn bei dieser Frage geht es um die feine Unterscheidung oder Nichtunterscheidung zweier sehr verwandter Konzepte -- aber es geht nicht um hunderte von Einzelkriterien, die wir jedes für sich ermitteln und abwägen müssen, was im Vergleich zum präzisen Nutzen "Frage beantwortet" viel zu aufwändig wäre und in Erbsenzählerei ausartete.

Ergo habe auch ich soeben keine Erbsen gezählt, sondern nur ein Haar gespalten.

Comment: +1 (geht übrigens in die gleiche Richtung wie die Antwort von user unknown, finde ich)

Comment: Ja, stimmt. Was mir an seiner Antwort einerseits gefällt, aber einen Unterschied zu meiner darstellt: Er unterscheidet auch anhand der relativen Mühe, die mit der Erbsenzählerei bzw. Haarspalterei verbunden ist. No thought of mine, daher separate Antwort okay finde ich. Ich upvote mal seine ;)

Comment: +1 stimme vollständig zu. Aber diese ganzen Wortspiele bei dieser Frage treiben einen ja in den Wahnsinn. ^^

Comment: @Ladybug: That´s what we are here for, no?

Comment: Da ist ein Widerspruch: Unter Erbsenzählerei wird gesagt, dass das genannte Beispiel eben *keine* Haarspalterei wäre, um im nächsten Absatz zu behaupten, dass man jede Erbsenzählerei als Haarspalterei bezeichnen kann. Die Mengen mögen sich überschneiden, aber es ist nicht eine in der anderen enthalten. Ich finde, das ist ein angemessen pendantischer Kommentar für dieses Thema :)

Answer (score 12):

Ich würde sagen: Probier es aus (Haarspalten und Erbsenzählen). Zweiteres ist langwierig und erfordert viel Geduld, ist aber leicht zu machen. Ersteres erfordert dagegen äußerstes Geschick.

Im täglichen Gebrauch wird wohl selten auf diesen Unterschied geachtet - wollte ich aber die Schwierigkeit des Unterfangens ausdrücken, würde ich zur Haarspalterei greifen. Den Erbsenzähler dagegen würde ich bei Pedanterie in Bezug auf eine Menge hervorholen.

Im Moment sehe ich mich eher als spitzfindigen Haarspalter. :)

Answer (score 11):

Der [**Erbsenzähler**](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erbsenz%C3%A4hler) bezeichnet umgangssprachlich und ironisch abwertend einen auf Genauigkeit und Vollständigkeit bedachten Menschen (oder sein Handeln). Laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erbsenz%C3%A4hler) stammt der Begriff "Erbsenzähler" von einem Ausspruch eines Zeitgenossen über **Karl Baedeker**:

> Der umgangssprachliche Begriff des Erbsenzählers für pingelige
>   Korrektheit (Pedanterie) stammt von einem Ausspruch eines Zeitgenossen
>   über Karl Baedeker, einen Herausgeber von Reiseführern. Beim Besteigen
>   des Mailänder Doms ertappte der westfälische Freiherr Gisbert von
>   Vincke 1847 Baedeker dabei, wie dieser alle 20 Stufen stehen blieb und
>   eine trockene Erbse von der Westen- in die Hosentasche steckte. Mit 20
>   multipliziert, ergab die Zahl der Erbsen plus Reststufen die präzise
>   Stufenangabe für den späteren Reiseführer. Beim Abstieg machte er dann
>   die Gegenprobe. Eben jener Genauigkeit verdankt er vermutlich auch
>   seine Verewigung in Jacques Offenbachs Operette „La Vie Parisienne“,
>   in deren englischer Übersetzung es heißt: „Kings and governments may
>   err, but never Mr. Baedeker“.

Der [**Haarspalter**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haarspalter) ist laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haarspalter)

> jemand, der unwichtigen Kleinigkeiten übertriebene Bedeutung beimisst
>   und diese als Argumentation für oder gegen etwas heranzieht; jemand,
>   der spitzfindig ist.

Als Synonyme für Haarspalter gibt z. B. [synonyme.woxikon](http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/haarspalter.php) unter anderem an:

> Besserwisser, Federfuchser, Wortklauber, Krämerseele,
>   Kleinigkeitskrämer, Pedant

Online konnte ich kein Synonym für "Erbsenzähler" finden, würde aber zu "Pedant" tendieren.

**Schlußfolgerung:**

- Der **Erbsenzähler** bezeichnet einen Menschen, der auf Genauigkeit allerhöchsten Wert legt (die Zahl, z. B. die Anzahl der Treppen, muß genau stimmen).
- Der **Haarspalter** reitet auf unwichtigen Kleinigkeiten herum, denen er eine übertriebene Bedeutung beimisst.

So gesehen, könnte ein "Erbsenzähler" auch als "Haarspalter" gesehen werden, aber **nicht** umgekehrt.

**Ergänzung:**

Auf Wikipedia findet sich noch der Begriff des umgangssprachlichen 
[**Korinthenkackers**](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korinthenkacker), "der besonders pedantische kleinliche Menschen bezeichnet".

Comment: Andererseits werden beide Begriffe sehr oft im selben Kontext benutzt... Somit müsste man schon ein großer Erbsenzähler sein, um zu behaupten, dass in diesem Satz Haarspalter das bessere Wort gewesen wäre. (Falls das überhaupt ein Satz war...)

Answer (score 8):

Vom Prinzip her lassen die beiden sich untereinander austauschen.

Allerdings ist für bestimmte Fälle, wie wenn es zum Beispiel um Geld oder sonstige zählbare Einheiten geht, das Wort Erbsenzähler besser geignet bzw. klingt in dem Zusammenhang besser.
(Das ist aber natürlich rein subjektiv.)
Haarspalter lässt sich da etwas universeller einsetzen. Außerdem klingt es etwas förmlicher.

Answer (score 3):

Meiner Erfahrung nach sind die beiden Begriffe größtenteils austauschbar, wobei ich "Erbsenzähler" eher im engeren Freundeskreis verwenden würde, da es meiner Ansicht nach leichter als beleidigend verstanden werden kann.

Aber beide Begriffe beschreiben im Grunde dasselbe kleinliche und pedantische Verhalten.