# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "wolkig" und "bewölkt"?

Tags: difference, adjective

Das mag [Haarspalterei](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/gibt-es-einen-unterschied-zwischen-haarspalterei-und-erbsenzahlerei) sein, aber meine Wettervorhersage meinte neulich, das Wetter sei heute *bewölkt* und morgen *wolkig*. Das Wetter war an beiden Tagen sehr ähnlich.

Gibt es doch einen Unterschied?

Comment: +1 fürs Erscheinen des (für mich neuen und interessanten) Begriffes *Haarspalterei*.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Hat nix mit Haarspalterei zu tun, sondern mit Fachtermini:
[Bewölkung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bew%C3%B6lkung)

Bewölkt ist ein zu 5/8 bedeckter Himmel, wolkig nur 4/8. (Was ich als Laie jetzt genau umgekehrt geschätzt hätte.)

Comment: D.h: Bewölkt bedeutet etwas mehr Wolken als wolkig.

Comment: als Laie würde ich den Unterschied zwischen 5/8 und 4/5 wahrscheinlich nicht bemerken :)

Comment: @ladybug: Es soll 4/8 und nicht 4/5 sein. Weil es eine zu kleine "edit" ist, musst du es selber tun. Ich kann es nicht, auf jeden Fall. :)

Comment: @Stovner: danke :)

Comment: Im Wikipedia-Artikel steht: "9/8 Himmel nicht erkennbar". Hä? :-)

Comment: @splattne: xD ist mir gar nicht aufgefallen... vielleicht meinen sie den Weltuntergang damit? Oder vielleicht einfach Nebel/Dunst, so dass man den Himmel nicht einschätzen kann. return -1 quasi ^^

Comment: ...oder es heißt einfach, dass der Meteorologe zu faul ist, aufzustehen und aus dem Fenster zu schauen. ^^

Comment: "Sky obscured by fog and/or other meteorological phenomena / Cloud cover is indiscernible for reasons other than fog or other meteorological phenomena, or observation is not made" http://www.srh.noaa.gov/ohx/dad/ua/rrs/Clouds%20Codes.pdf

Comment: Aha, also doch zu faul zum Aufstehen... xD

Comment: Den Unterschied zwischen 4/8 und 5/8 Bewoelkung zu definieren ist "Wolkenspalterei" - I am very sorry!

Comment: Wenn der Unterschied zwischen 4/8 und 5/8 nicht haarspalterisch ist, was dann?

Answer (score 4):

[Hier findet man Wettersymbole](http://www.wetteronline.de/symbole). Wie du siehst, beim "wolkig" sieht man ein kleines bisschen von der Sonne aber beim "bewölkt" sieht man nichts ausser den Wolken.

<sup>[Copyright protected content removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6LPD.jpg)</sup>

The [source](http://www.wetteronline.de/symbole) of the image

Answer (score -1):

Bewölkt deckt ein viel grösseres Spektrum ab als wolkig.

Ein tiefschwarzer Sommergewitter-Himmel kann mit bewölkt beschrieben werden aber nicht mit wolkig. Wolkig hat etwas lockeres, es sollte mindestens hie und da ein bisschen blauer Himmel zu sehen sein, sonst würd ich das nich mehr wolkig nennen sondern stark bewölkt.

Daher ohne mathematische Wolkenspalterei:

wolkig = leicht bis mittel bewölkt

Answer (score -3):

Bewölkt heißt, es gibt mehr Wolken als "wolkig".

Comment: Weicht die Ansicht von der ladybugs ab? Inwiefern? Wenn nicht, wieso nicht einfach diese upvoten?

Comment: Die Antwort ist nicht falsch, Downvotes sind übertrieben.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Zum Downvoten muss die Antwort nicht falsch sein, sondern "not useful".