# Distinction between "bewölkt" and "bedeckt"

Tags: difference, adjective

While I read some story I found two terms that confusing me: *Bewölkt* and *bedeckt.* Both of them are same to me, or I am wrong.

Is there any distinction?

Comment: The German Wikipedia has a nice [article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bew%C3%B6lkung) on this. See the table at the right side of the page.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/gibt-es-einen-unterschied-zwischen-wolkig-und-bew%c3%b6lkt

Answer (score 8):

**Bedeckt** means that the whole sky is covered by clouds (there is a continuous layer of clouds without any significant gaps)

**Bewölkt** means that there are quite a lot of clouds, but the cover is not continuous

Answer (score 8):

In meteorology, the amount of cloud cover (the fraction of the sky that is obscured by clouds) is usually given in eighths (octa or okta). According to Germany’s National Meteorological Service, the *Deutscher Wetterdienst (DWD)*, the cloud cover is described as follows:

0/8 wolkenlos
1/8 sonnig
2/8 heiter
3/8 leicht bewölkt
4/8 wolkig
5/8 bewölkt
6/8 stark bewölkt
7/8 fast bedeckt
8/8 bedeckt

Answer (score 1):

Another explanation:

**Bewölkt:** I can see distinct clouds, with (more or less) defined shapes, sizes and borders.

**Bedeckt:** The whole sky looks like a grey veil (hence *bedeckt* - *covered*), I can't identify actual clouds i.e. it's impossible to say where one cloud would end and another one starts.