# Translations for Weather-Descriptions

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I am trying to translate some weather descriptions for a weather-application to German. I managed to translate many of them, but I am still stuck with a few. I hope you can help me with it:

- ragged shower rain
- shower sleet
- light rain and snow
- rain and snow
- sand
- dust

My attempts in German:

- Regenschauer (but what is *ragged* in this context)
- Schneeregen?
- Leichter Schneeregen?
- Schnee und Regen?
- Sandig?
- Staubig?

Do you have better translations, because I’m not quite happy with them, yet.

---

About the App:

It just shows some basic weather information of the current weather and a 7 days forecast.
For the current weather I also have a weather description, that my weather provider gives me. For these texts I need translations. See attached screenshot. In this example it would be *sunny* = (*sonnig*).

But I have some problems with *sand* or *dust* for example. What kind of weather-description is *sandig* or *staubig*? I have never seen this before …

[image]

Comment: Good morning. You might get more and better answers if you'd include the app's definition for each item you need help with, and why you're not happy with the translations you found.

Comment: I definitely recommend to ask Rob McKenna.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Thanks. I have updated the question

Comment: What are "sand" and "dust" weather?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea... that's why I'm asking... See here (Codes 751 / 761) http://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions

Comment: Related: [Distinction between “bewölkt” and “bedeckt”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/15466/9551)

Comment: By way of comparison, standardized weather reports in the [METAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR) format are used in aviation. This format includes [special events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR#METAR_WX_codes) such as limited visibility due to dust (DU) or sand (SA). A German translation can be found [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR#Besondere_Wettererscheinungen).

Comment: @Loong beat me to it. As a former pilot, I also would have suggested going by aviation weather sites and then their international translations. In fact, you should expand it into an answer!

Comment: You're right. The weather codes of my weather provider all (at least most of them) seem to use official and standardised weather-codes. This way I will find the 100% correct translations. This should be an answer. ;)

Comment: @Loong I think your comment makes the best possible answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For standardised weather descriptions, one can always fall back to the [METAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR) format. The German Wikipedia provides an overview including [translations](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR#Besondere_Wettererscheinungen) for some but not all of your problematic terms.

*Ragged showers* or *thunderstorms* seems to indicate on and off according to bits and bobs of information I found on the internet. Thus I would propose *wiederkehrende Regenschauer* for *ragged shower rain.*

*Sleet* is *Schneeregen* and *showers* are of course *Schauer*, so *shower sleet* is *Schneeregenschauer*.

Distinguish between *Schneeregen* (*sleet*) and *Schnee und Regen* (*snow and rain*). The former is both in one, the latter is both but not at the same time. Probably, we need something like *leichter, in Schnee übergehender Regen* for *light rain and snow*.

*Sand* and *dust* are visibility issues due to sand or dust. The Wikipedia translations list *Sand* und *verbreitet Staub*.